# how to re-init JQuery autocomplete in a refreshed DIV?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have DIV, inside it an autocomplete widget copied form the JQuery samples: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/default.html

At button presses, the content of the DIV is replaced with new HTML, with the HEADER containing dynamically generated  Javascript to initialize the autocomplete

```
<head> .. 
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

My problem is: the $(function()) is not evaluated at subequent reloads of the DIV == autocomplete does not work .

Surprise surprise, there is no "ready" event for DIVs

Please advise how to re-initialize the autocomplete code.

The main page contains a PROJECT selector, on change will reload the DIV with dynamically generated details including an autocomplete widget.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function refresh_div() {
    ..    
    document.getElementById(DYNA_DIV).innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
   }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <select id=PROJECT_ID onchange="refresh_div()" ..>
 <div id="DYNA_DIV"> ..here is dynamically generated form with autocomplete widget containing items related to the PROJECT selected above</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML for the DIV is bellow. Stripped off the HTML, HEAD, BODY as suggested

At first load autocomplete works. When refreshing the content of the DIV, the initializer script bellow does not run

```
  ..  <input type="text" name="AUTOCOMP"> ..

 <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableItems = [ <% dynamically enumerate items for PROECT_ID %> ];

        $( "#AUTOCOMP" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableItems
        });
    });    

  </script>
```

-alex

Comment: If you're replacing the contents of a div, could you not put the autocomplete code in a function at the root of the document and then re-instantiate it after your code to update the contents of the div?

Answer (score 1):

Do you replace content of `DIV` with full HTML tree

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>...
```

If yes then unless you include this new tree by creating `IFRAME` element, your content is ignored by browser. You should just output content you want to put inside `DIV` (without tags: `HTML`, `HEAD` and all it's tags, `BODY`) and only include what's inside your `BODY`. You can also include `SCRIPT` inside `BODY` if that's what you need here.

**UPDATE**:

After you updated you question I see one error. Maybe it's mistake in question only, but let's try:

You have `"#AUTOCOMP"` selector, but you have `<input type="text" name="AUTOCOMP">`. If that's how your content look's like, then you should select input by `'input[name="AUTOCOMP"]'` selector instead.

Comment: Yes, if you ever include an HTML tag inside a DIV, your markup is already broken and technically won't validate. It sounds like a slightly hacky approach has been taken. Probably best to make the button presses fire off an AJAX request to get the data and then re-initialize the autocomplete when done.

Comment: tried to reply with only <table>..</table> <script> .. </script>, no help

Comment: @TothAlexandru Can you confirm that function inside newly fetched SCRIPT tag is executed? Try adding console.info calls inside it and check with Firebug/Chrome Inspector/Opera Dragonfly if you see anything. This way you can also check if your selector (`$("#AUTOCOMP")`) properly selects new element instead of old.

Comment: Javascript is executed, exactly once, on first load. So it selects correctly the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in an `add_load`:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {

    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

});
```

Comment: The Sys.Application.add_load does not work even at first load